# Lagom how to decide on the entity id

Tags: scala, akka, persistent, lagom

I am trying to add user and friend services using lagom framework. I read lagom persistent doc but still not able to understand how should I decide on entity id? Since it should be unique to retrieve it back. The random uuid generated is one option but that would be unusable since while sending command those uuid will not be available to other user/services.
Here are two solutions I can think of:
1) use email as entity id.
2) push the uuid and user name/id in database so that service retrieve uuid and then send command.

As per my understanding Solution 2 is two step process and defeats the purpose.
Solution 1, for other services like friend service there might be cases which can be duplicated or needs to send more information to retrieve the entity id.

Also I couldn’t find a better way to implement dean on services in this framework. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are no simple answers to your question, because it all depends on how the interaction between the services will look. But you should think about Entity Id as a unique identifier which also doesn't change in time. Changing Entity Id means creating new entity. In my opinion, email is not a good candidate for an Entity Id, because user may change it and also use more than one. I would go for UUID and would keep track on emails, plus expose methods which can handle communication between the services using for example user email (one of his emails), phone number(s), 3rd party service Ids, etc.

Comment: Where do we keep track of the UUID and emails? either we can use database to keep track of it  and do a read using readside processor. but then it will be twice the amount of work. or in memory map of UUID and emails.

Comment: Yes, storing UUID and emails in a repository (Cassandra for instance) and reading it using readside processor would be my preffered option. Regarding a memory map (cache?), check if you are not trying to prematurely optimize (google the 'Premature optimization').